# Figma plugin VectorNode doesn't have .fillGeometry?

Tags: typescript, figma, figma-api

The [VectorNode documentation](https://www.figma.com/plugin-docs/api/VectorNode/#fillgeometry) claims that `VectorNode` has a property called `fillGeometry`.

However, TypeScript disagrees, saying that "property 'fillGeometry' does not exist on type 'VectorNode'"

[image: typescript error]

What am I missing here?  I would really like an example of how to set `fillGeometry` on a `VectorNode`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `VectorNode` you're referencing is using an outdated or incorrect typings file. The correct type definition for `VectorNode` should include the `fillGeometry` property.

You can either try to update the typings to the latest version or if it's not available, you can use a type assertion to manually tell TypeScript to treat the `VectorNode` as if it has a `fillGeometry` property:

```
(node as any).fillGeometry = ...
```

This will allow you to access the `fillGeometry` property, but keep in mind that you'll lose some of the type safety benefits of using TypeScript.

Alternatively, you can try to reach out to the author of the `VectorNode` plugin for an updated typings file or clarification on the correct way to access the `fillGeometry` property.